# Kendo UI functions too slow: toDataURL and saveAsExcel

Tags: kendo-ui, todataurl

I have a kendo UI grid with 9 sheets, 2 of those sheets have 1200 columns and 600 rows, I'm trying to export that to excel with a custom code so I'm using toDataURLAsync, I also tried toDataURL but both are extremely slow, same problem with saveAsExcel function, I wait for around 30 minutes but I never get the file or data, the code is functional with smaller grids, What could I do to improve the performance? This is my code, It seems not calling onSelect, onChange, onSelectSheet nor getMaxColumns:

```
$("#spreadsheetToExport").kendoSpreadsheet({
    select: onSelect,
    change: onChange,
    selectSheet: onSelectSheet,
    excel: {
        // Required to enable saving files in older browsers
        proxyURL: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
    },
    pdf: {
        proxyURL: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
    },
    excelExport: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the Excel file as a data URL.
            var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook(e.workbook);
            var base64;
            workbook.toDataURLAsync().then(function (dataURL) {
                base64 = dataURL.split(";base64,")[1];

                //Custom code here
            });
    },
    sheets: sheetsToExcel,
    columns: getMaxColumns(),
    rows: 1000,
    columnWidth: 120
});
```

Comment: Grid or Spreadsheet? Kendo has added grid optimizations in the 2020R1 release.

Comment: Spreadsheet for JQuery

Comment: It is not clear to me if the code slows down on kendo's functions or in your custom code. Does it reaches your custom code or the promisse(`workbook.toDataURLAsync().then`) is never called?

Comment: For example, if I change the code to call toDataURL(), this line last too long, after 30 minutes I don't get the result. In the example in the post I'm using toDataURLAsync() so, in that case, it doesn´t reach the promise, I'm just waiting around 30 minutes so it's taking longer than that, as I mentioned, if I test this with smaller spreadsheets, it works, so it's a performance issue with kendo, not my code.